# foundry error for forge install

Tags: foundry

Error:
This command requires clean working and staging areas, including no untracked files. Modify .gitignore and/or add/commit first, or add the --no-commit option.

What if I don't want to commit code yet

How to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You may already be inside a git folder when doing this command. In general it is best to use forge outside of another git folder (this is what is meant with "clean").

Use the following command to use foundry without git:

`forge init --no-git` or `forge init --no-commit`

I'm assuming you're using forge init. In case you want to use `forge install` use the following commands `forge install --no-git` or `forge install --no-commit` but do note that normally dependencies are installed as git submodules.

The foundry book is a great resource, I recommend browsing for any general issue.

Source:

https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/forge/forge-init?highlight=--no-git#options

https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/forge/forge-install

Comment: Thanks for response, but I have question I am working on smart contract and I want to install something say, forge install transmissions11/solmate and it throws that error. yes, I am inside the root of project. If I remove all changes and do install all work fine. it's only when there is uncommitted changes . What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you already are in the root of a project, you need to be in a "clean" environment. This means there is not .git or .gitignore files in the folder structure above. Do you have such files in folders that may be above it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install dependencies in a foundry project which is also a git repository, your best option is `forge install --no-commit` which installs the dependency as a git submodule.

There is also `forge install --no-git` but I would use that only if I have a specific reason to.